# Maven 3 Junit 3 Tests Are Not Running

Tags: java, maven-3, junit3

**Tools :**

Maven 3

JUnit 3

**Issue :**

I have a legacy project which uses `JUnit 3.` 
I have created  a new test module with `src/test/java` as project structure and added `JUnits 3` classes inside it.

JUnits classes follow correct naming convention as - `Test*.java`

But when I run `mvn clean test` , maven is not picking up the tests.

It seems `no tests to run` message is also not coming given by `maven-surefire-plugin`

Can anybody please advice what is the issue here  ?

I am really not able to find why tests are not picked up

Comment: If you added tests to a legacy project, then are there old tests already? Do those run? If so, you could compare your new ones and the old ones. Also try running "mvn -X clean test" to figure out what's happening.

Comment: I haven't added any new tests. These are existing ones . I just moved them to a new folder structure to get picked by maven

Comment: Running mvn -X clean test is not listing running of surefire plugin

Comment: The name of the class should be `xxxTest`

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in `pom.xml` .

The packaging was declared as `<packaging>pom</packaging>`

The packaging is changed to jar and it started working